# Is it good to have an idea about the STL before studying Data Structures?

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++, stl

I'm currently self-studying C++ and I'm about to finish my OOP course, till now, I've finished the OOP concepts but the course also includes an introduction to the STL, but I feel like it's too early to have a look on the STL at this stage(before studying Data Structures).
Is it a good idea to skip the last part of the OOP course and start studying Data Structures right now? or should I complete the course anyway?

Comment: Learning how to *use* the STL does not require knowledge of data structures. Conversely, learning the theory of data structures work does not require exposure to the STL - or C++. One perfectly valid way of teaching is to introduce how something is used and later dig into theory of why it works.  Another way is to teach the theory and later teach about how the theory can be applied. So a "data structures in C++" course could notionally teach how to use the STL first and later the theory of data structures or, conversely, it could teach theory of data structures first and then how to use STL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, if you already can understand OOP principles you should use STL and do not care how it really works under the hood, but after that, you should learn basic data structures and all will come clear for you.